# MongoDB low CPU and performance

Tags: mongodb, centos, centos7, redhat, pymongo-3.x

I have a MongoDB running on a server with 2GB of RAM and one vCPU. The OS is CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908. I have a Python script which used pymongo driver. There is a for loop with about 10 iterations, each iteration executing an aggregate query on the database. The problem is that for the first 5 iterations the CPU is around 100%, which is expected, but for the other 5 it decreases to about 20%, which lowers me the performance and it takes a lot more time for the last 5 queries to get a result. Why is this happening and the CPU is not the same for all the queries? The only difference between the queries is a parameter on a $match. Is there a setting from Mongo or CentOS which keeps my processor down after a period?

The query used looks like this:

```js
db.data_col.aggregate({
                "$match": {
                    "reading_date": date
                }
            },
            {
                "$group": {
                    "_id": "$user",
                    "count": {
                        "$sum": 1
                    },
                    "value": {
                        "$max": "$value"
                    }
                }
            }
)
```

I have indexes on reading_date, user, value.

Comment: it's hard to say without seeing all the queries. and receiving additional information like collection indexes and so on.

Comment: I've added the query the the indexes. Thanks!